# nodejs app running on node server but not showing any output

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

hi i'm new in nodejs.

```js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('server running....on Pro');

app.get ('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

    io.sockets.on('connections',function(socket){
 connections.push(socket);
 console.log('connected: %s sockets is connected', connections.length);

 //Disconnet function 
 socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  
  users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username),1);
  updateUsernames();
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
  console.log('Disconneted: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
 });
 //send messege
 socket.on('send massege', function(data){
 io.sockets.emit('new massege', {msg: data, user:socket.username});
 });

 //new user
 socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
  callback(true);
  socket.username = data;
  user.push(socket.username);
  updateUsernames();

 });
 function updateUsernames(){
  io.sockets.emit('get users', users);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Simple Chat App By Probhas</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <style>
  body{
   margin-top: 30px;
  }
    #messageArea{
      display: none;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div id="userFormArea" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form id="userForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Enter Username</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="Username"><br/>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div id="messageArea" class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="well">
       <h3>Online Users</h3>
       <ul class="list_group" id="users"></ul>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-8"></div>
      <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
      <form id="messageform">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter Your Massege</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="send Massege">
       </div>
      </form>
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <script>
    $(function(){
     var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageform = $('#messageform');
        var $message = $('#messageform');
        var $chat = $('chat');
        var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
        var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
        var $userForm = $('#userForm');
        var $users = $('#users');
        var $Username = $('#Username');

          $messageform.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send massege', $message.val());
            $message.val('');
          });
          socket.on('new massege', function(data){
            $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>:'+data.msg+'</div>');
          });

          $userform.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('new user', $Username.val(),function(data){
              if (data){
                $userFormArea.hide();
                $messageArea.show();

              }
            });
            $Username.val('');
          });
          socket.on('get users', function(data){
            var html = '';
            for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              html += '<li class = "list-group-item">'+data[i]+'</li>';
             }
             $users.html(html);
          });
    });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i build a real-time chat application using socket.io, Node.js and Express. i followed the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE) i code same as tutorial and the app in running in node server on my localhost. but it don't showing any-output.i think it's can problem with my variable declaration and id in html.but i didn't find the errors till now. here is my server.js file and index.html file

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: `io.sockets.on('connections'`? Maybe `io.sockets.on('connection'`?

Comment: **no** @Rastalamm

Comment: pls update to include server code to show how you are creating object :  server

Comment: Where do you define `server` and `app`?

Comment: does it show the `index.html` page on route `/`

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397302/socket-io-and-node-js-chat-does-not-display-on-screen/38399155#38399155

Answer (score 1):

Here this will work:

**index.js:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('server running....on Pro');


io.on('connection',function(socket){
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('connected: %s sockets is connected', connections.length);

    //Disconnet function 
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){

        users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username),1);
        updateUsernames();
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
        console.log('Disconneted: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
    });
    //send messege
    socket.on('send massege', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('new massege', {msg: data, user:socket.username});
    });

    //new user
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        callback(true);
        socket.username = data;
        users.push(socket.username);
        updateUsernames();

    });
    function updateUsernames(){
        io.sockets.emit('get users', users);
    }
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Chat App By Probhas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    #messageArea{
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="userFormArea" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form id="userForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Enter Username</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="Username"><br/>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div id="messageArea" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>Online Users</h3>
                    <ul class="list_group" id="users"></ul>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
                <form id="messageform">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Your Massege</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea><br/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="send Massege">
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/");
        var $messageform = $('#messageform');
        var $message = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');
        var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
        var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
        var $userForm = $('#userForm');
        var $users = $('#users');
        var $Username = $('#Username');

          $messageform.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send massege', $message.val());
            $message.val('');
          });

          socket.on('new massege', function(data){
            $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>:'+data.msg+'</div>');
          });

          $userForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('new user', $Username.val(),function(data){
              if (data){
                $userFormArea.hide();
                $messageArea.show();

              }
            });
            $Username.val('');
          });
          socket.on('get users', function(data){
            var html = '';
            for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              html += '<li class = "list-group-item">'+data[i]+'</li>';
             }
             $users.html(html);
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I changed a few little things. This config is good for local running, when you host it on a website later you should/could improve some things for security purpose, but for now it's a good set-up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var Server = require('socket.io');
var io = new Server();
```

However please check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624953/8062856)